# $.post() и json

Tags: jquery, json, php

```
$.post('/users', {}, function(data) {
 alert(data);
});
```

data содержит:

> {"status" : "ok"}

Как получить значение status, не используя getJson() в jquery, а используя $.post()?

```
data.status
```

не срабатывает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/users',
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.success);
    }
});
```

Или

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Но это будет действовать для вообще всех AJAX-запросов через jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Ну как обычно чтобы взломали (*eval()*)то так

```
var d = eval('('+data+')');
alert(d.status)
```

Comment: А чтоб не взломали?

Comment: @knes ты издеваешься? :)
Обсуждали же не раз, как избавиться от eval() :) 

пусть хоть немного подумают как можно что-то улучшить в этом мире.

Comment: Издеваюсь, конечно. Зачем муру плодить, если есть нормальные методы.
А то до сих пор встречаю

    mysql_%funcname%(...) or die(mysql_error());

Рай для инфомайнинга.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
data.status // та-да!
```

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто:

```
$.post('/users', {}, function(data) {
 alert(data.status);
},'json');
```